# Ember.js - Animate Handlebars Change

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I am using an {{if}} statement in a handlebars template (in Ember.js) and currently have it setup so if *foo* is true, a form is displayed.

I have a button which toggles the value of *foo* and hides/shows the form. This is done with an {{action}} attribute.

What I would like to do is animate this change. If possible, how can I do this using the current setup?

Note: I would be fine with fadeIn/fadeOut (jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Liquid Fire (see: https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire). I personally didn't work with it yet, but the examples look promising.  Especially this form example looks similar to what you want: http://ef4.github.io/ember-animation-demo/#/animated-if-demo
Source is on the next slide: http://ef4.github.io/ember-animation-demo/#/animated-if-source

Comment: Yeah, Edward is doing great work. He did a [nice presentation at Emberconf](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/3302-emberconf2014-animations-and-transitions-in-an-ember-app) on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

in the handlebars file:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="newPost">
     <p> Template for New Post </p>
     <div class="errorMsg">
         <p>Error Message</p>
     </div>
</script>
```

in the view you can set a trigger with an action, and hide the div with the message error

```
App.NewPostView = Ember.View.extend({
    showError: function() {
        $('.errorMsg').fadeToggle("slow");
    },
    didInsertElement : function(){
        $('.errorMsg').hide();
        this.get('controller').on('showError', this, this.showError);
    },
    willClearRender: function()
    {
      this.get('controller').off('showError', this, this.showError);
    }
});
```

And finally in the controller, this must extend to Ember.Evented and when you want to show the message error, you must call a this.trigger error.

```
App.NewPostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Evented,{
    actions:{
         // This an example the method that verify and show error after validating
         addNewPost: function(post){
             if(post.get('name') === 'valid'){
                  //do your business                       
             }else{
                  //this will show the message error
                  this.trigger('showError');
             }
         }
    }

})
```

when you want to hide the message error, you must call this.trigger('showError') again and this hide the message, you can use this with other effects.